# Accumulators not showing up in Spark UI

Tags: scala, apache-spark, accumulator

I have implemented Accumulators to see counts of events in my code. But I cannot see them in the Spark UI.
I am using the following things :

```
val  count_Of_2317508_1 = sc.longAccumulator("count_Of_2317508_1")
 count_Of_2317508_1.add(1)
```

on some condition.

Is this enough for it to show up on the Spark UI?

Comment: If it's not invoked (no action), then it's not shown.

Answer (score 5):

You can create accumulators with or without a name, but only [named accumulators](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-accumulators.html#named) are displayed in web UI (under Stages tab for a given stage).

Since you have already created named accumulator it should come.

```
val counter = sc.longAccumulator("counter")
```

[image]